# Django form doesn't send data

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to add a user to some events in the calendar (using fullcalendar), but when putting the form to request the data from the user, this form does not send me the data. How can I get the data it is supposed to send?

This is my event_register.html:

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
    <p>Apuntarse como invitado.</p>
    <form  action="" method="POST"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">Nombre:</label> 
            <!--<input id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Nombre del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.first_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last_name">Apellidos:</label> 
            <!--<input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Apellidos del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.last_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Teléfono:</label> 
            <!--<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.phone}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Correo electrónico:</label> 
            <!--<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.email}}
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Enviar">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-6">

</div>
```

This is my view.py:

```
def attend_to(request):

event_form = EventForm()
print('Hola')

if request.method == 'POST':
    event_form = EventForm(data=request.POST)
    if event_form.is_valid():
        Assistant.objects.create(UserManegement=None, Event=request.event_id, frist_name=request.POST["first_name"], last_name=request.POST["last_name"], phone=request.POST["phone"], email=request.POST["email"])
        return render(request, "core/home.html")
else:
    Assistant.objects.create(UserManegement=request.POST["user"], Event=request.POST["event"])
    return render( "core/home.html")
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class EventForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(label="first_name", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Escribe tu nombre'}
), min_length=3, max_length=100)
last_name = forms.CharField(label="last_name", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Apellidos'}
), min_length=3, max_length=100)
phone = forms.CharField(label="phone", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Telefono'}
), min_length=9, max_length=9)
email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=True,  widget=forms.EmailInput(
    attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Escribe tu email'}
), min_length=3, max_length=100)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.attend_to, name='attend_to'),

]
```

And this is what I receive when clicking on the button:

```
"POST /event/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6249
```

This is the view that renders the event_register.html view, I have a calendar with fullcalendar and when clicking on an event it shows me that template.

```
def register_event(request, event_id):
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
return render(request, "events/event_register.html", {'event':event})
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
I don't know what the problem is now, but when I click on the event to open the url that contains the form, it doesn't show me the corresponding template. It is as if it did not enter the if request.method == 'POST'. Here I leave the updated code.

The view what renders the template event_register.html:

```
def register_event(request, event_id):
event_form = EventForm()
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
return render(request, "events/event_register.html", {'event':event, 
'form':event_form})
```

The template what contains the form:

```
<form  action="{% url 'attend_to' %}" method="POST"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">Nombre:</label> 
            <!--<input id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Nombre del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.frist_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

urls.py core to load the template:

```
urlpatterns = [
#Path del core
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
path('event/<int:event_id>/', include('events.urls'), name='attend_to'),

]
```

urls.py for events:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.attend_to, name='attend_to'),

]
```

The views.py what contains attend_to, it's show me the print('Hola'):

```
def attend_to(request, event_id):

event_form = EventForm()
print('Hola')

if request.method == 'POST':
    event_form = EventForm(request.POST)
    if event_form.is_valid():
        event_form.save()
        context = {"form":event_form}
        Assistant.objects.create(UserManegement=None, Event=request.event_id, frist_name=context.first_name, last_name=context.last_name, phone=context.phone, email=context.email)
        
        #Assistant.objects.create(UserManegement=None, Event=request.event_id, frist_name=request.POST["first_name"], last_name=request.POST["last_name"], phone=request.POST["phone"], email=request.POST["email"])
        #return render(request, "core/home.html")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        #return render("core/home.html", context)
#else:
#    Assistant.objects.create(UserManegement=request.POST["user"], Event=request.POST["event"])
#    return render( "core/home.html")
else:
    event_form = EventForm()
return render(request, 'core/home.html', {'form': event_form})
```

The response what shows me the server:

```
[24/Feb/2021 10:27:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9404
Hola
```

Comment: Is the form not valid when you submit the form or are you not seeing the form fields in the template at all?

Comment: @Danoram If I uncomment the fields of the html form, the fields appear but I can't get it to send anything. If I put the form fields with {form.first_name}, the fields do not appear.

Comment: The fields do not appear with `{form.first_name}` because you haven't put the form in the view's context. At least, not from the code you have provided. This leads into the next question which is, the form html is in a template called `event_register.html` but the view function you provided does not render this view? Can you provide the view function code that renders `event_register.html` please

Comment: I just edited to show the view. @Danoram

Answer (score 0):

Use Model Form instead of form.Forms

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = In which You want to save data
        fields = "__all__" If you want to select all fields from your model or you can specify the list of fields in a list or tuple
        fields = ("field1","Field2","field3")
```

This form will automatically map all your Model Field to HTML
and just render this form in HTML.In View also you dont need to write so much code

```
def attend_to(request):
    event_form = EventForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       event_form = EventForm(request.POST)
       if event_form.is_valid():
           event_form.save()
           return redirect()#After Form submission use redirect.Never use render as it can create duplicate enteries on refresh.
    context = {"form":event_form}#Passing the form in HTML
    return render( "core/home.html",context)
```

HTML

```
 {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Nombre:</label> 
        {{form.fieldname}}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.first_name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last_name">Apellidos:</label> 
        <!--<input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Apellidos del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.last_name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Teléfono:</label> 
        <!--<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.phone}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Correo electrónico:</label> 
        <!--<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico del participante" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">-->
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.email}}
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Enviar">
    </div>
</form>
```

You can use load_widget_tweaks to style your form instead of writing code in your form

Comment: I have done what you have put, and the fields of the form do not appear. Neither uncommenting the labels of the html so that the fields appear works, I can't send anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add the blank form in the `register_event` view function.

```py
def register_event(request, event_id):
    event_form = EventForm()
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    return render(request, "events/event_register.html", {'event':event, 'form': event_form})
```

This will ensure the form fields are displayed in your `event_register.html` view that you can then submit.

Then in your form html, change the `action` attribute to submit the form data to the `attend_to` view function.

From this

```html
<form  action="" method="POST">
```

to this

```html
<form  action="{% url 'attend_to' %}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Well, now you can see the fields of the form. Now, when sending the form, it does not perform the attend_to function of the view. Do you know why it can be?

Comment: I will edit my answer to fix that problem as well

Comment: After doing that, it seems to work but it doesn't. I have put the updated code in the initial post with edit 1.

Comment: To clarify, the `event_register.html` template is not rendering now? Could you include all your paths in urls.py please

Comment: added full urls for both core and events in edit 1. 
And yes, it doesn't show me the template event_register which contains the form, but in the view function it goes on the else side

Comment: The else side of the `attend_to` view function?

Comment: Yes. It never goes into the if request.method == 'POST' check, and I don't know why that happens. But it also doesn't show me the template that the form contains.

Comment: The form is in the `register_event` view yes? Looking at your urls.py you don't have a path for that view

Comment: Alright, my fault.  I didn't have my app event urls in my app's global urls.py. Thank you very much for your help, your answer has saved my problem.

Comment: awesome! glad I was able to help